# Check mark character prevents text color with UIColor

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator

Read about the issue [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688980/ios-5-1-uilabel-with-heavy-check-mark-character-ignores-textcolor).

Still have the same issue after trying the solution. If I change the @"\u2714" to @"\u2418" the X is displayed in the requested color. The solution to not use system font didn't work for me. After switching the font for the text label from System to Custom Helvetica Bold 21.0, the check mark still displays in black, not green.

Comment: Discoved that many of the special characters with 'heavy' in their name will not accept color. This behavior is also seen in the storyboard when entering these from the Special Characters menu and selecting a color. They will not accept the color. Submitted a bug report on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zapf Dingbats works.

I guess for some reason the heavy checkmark character was given an Emoji graphic, even though it doesn't show up in the Emoji keyboard, and the system now uses that graphic for the character in every typeface that doesn't have its own version. Zapf Dingbats was the only "font variation" in the Character Viewer that's also one of the fonts on iOS.

Comment: Nice answer. That seems like a logical reason for the work/not work. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC According to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688980/ios-5-1-uilabel-with-heavy-check-mark-character-ignores-textcolor#comment12859494_9694802) "Arial Unicode MS" also works, but you'd have to set the font in code, because that's not an option in interface builder. iirc when I tried it, choosing "Arial" in IB didn't fix it. If this problem arises with other characters, you should be able to find which fonts have a version of that character in the OS X character viewer.